# Подключение внешних устройств к android по USB

Tags: java, android, usb

Пытаюсь создать подключение телефона(android) к внешним устройствам(TV) в качестве host. Для вывода на TV-экран текстового сообщения. 
Подскажите с каком направлении думать, а может кто то уже встречался с такой задачей.

Comment: я очень сомневаюсь, что TV захочет работать, как приемник ваших данных через USB.

Comment: Я вообще правильно понимаю вопрос? Вы хотите выводить на TV информацию со смартфона через USB? Такой себе USB-монитор?

Comment: Да именно, хочу передать изображение, нужно выводить на ТВ либо изображение либо просто цифры, если это возможно конечно

Comment: Тогда вам нужно смотреть спецификации каждой отдельно взятой модели телевизора. Но я на 99.98% уверен, что ни один телевизор такого не поддерживает

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, оказывается я не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Подключение не по USB а по HDMI. 
В Android есть класс для работы с дополнительными дисплеями, класс Presentation https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Presentation.html
который и позволяет подключать дополнительные дисплеи и работать с ними.
Вот еще пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432487/android-presentation-class-how-to-make-changes-on-the-presentation-view-dynami